# Order of an item in MySQL query result

Tags: php, sql, mysql, ajax

Is there a way to know the order of an specific item in a query result with traversing the whole set?

I have a web application that show user comments in Ajaxified way, I would like to send the user a link to their comments like this:

http://my.web/post/12345#comment_45

and using the hash value "comment_45" load the comment page with the given comment, but I don't know how to get the right page with traversing the whole result.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how or where this URL is generated, but I will assume that if you know which comment it is when the URL is created, you should know at a later time and date. It sounds like each comment has a unique ID (which it should if it doesn't).

I don't think having comment_45 reference a certain comment on a certain page is a reliable way of retreiving the comment later (what if another comment earlier in the page or on another page is deleted? what if you change how many comments display on a page? etc)

If comments have an ID, and the "comment_45" in your URL is in fact this ID, you could use the following general SQL query to retrieve only this comment:

```
select field1, field2, ... fieldn from comments where comment_id = id;
```

In this case, `id` would be a variable with the comment ID provided by the URL (the "45" portion of comment_45). As this information is coming from an untrusted source (the internet), you will want to make sure you sanitize the input to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: The URL would be found in the user own page, something like a profile page with link to all of his/her comments, I can get the comment ID, but I don't know the comment order. Knowing the order would allow me to view the correct page.

Comment: so you want other comments to appear as well, just the page has focused to the comment provided by the link, and there is the possibility of multiple comment pages

Answer (score 0):

Are your comments ordered in a sensible manner? If they're always displayed in numerical order from first to last (or last to first) you should be able to just compute what page it's on based on knowing a) the total number of comments, b) the number of comments per page.

Comment: The comments are sorted by time (newer first), so a user a comment with ID 45 could be on page 1 in morning, and page 4 in afternoon.

Comment: Yes, however if you know how many comments there are total, then you simply need to work backwards - for instance, if you have 120 comments total and 25 comments per page, then you know that 120 through 96 will be on page 1, 95 through 71 will be on page 2, 70 through 46 will be on page 3, and thus 45 would be the first comment on page 4. The only info you need to determine this is the 3 numbers for total comments, comments-per-page, and number of target comment. The page you want can be found via the formula `ceil( (total-target+1) / perpage )` assuming your pages are numbered beginning at 1.

Comment: Thank you Dav for clarification, I have 2 of the 3 numbers, I have total comments, and comments per page, but I don't have the number of the target comment, I only have its ID.
I could traverse the result until I get found the ID, but it won't be practical.

Comment: @rayed: Couldn't you just count the number of comments that come before the comment you're interested in (I'm assuming the comment IDs are done using an auto-increment field and are assigned in the order the comments were added)? Something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE post_id = 12345 AND comment_id < 45`. Then you could use Dav's algorithm to determine the page.

Comment: Exactly what Ken Keenan suggested - though in your particular case rayed you probably want to count comments that came *after* the target comment, not before - so you'd want to use > instead of <.

Answer (score 0):

Rows in an SQL database are by definition unordered. In order to guarantee the same order on subsequent queries, you must include an "order by" clause.  Then, you can do what you want with the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` ORDER BY `date_entered` LIMIT 45, 1
```

If rows are inserted or deleted between queries, the results won't be exactly what the user expects, but this is usually not a problem if the order-by field is a date-time.

Answer (score 0):

I am usually against using stored procedures in MySQL since I think they are not mature enough but I think this is a classic case to create one.

We are still required to have two queries, one for getting the comment's order and one for fetching the relevant rows but I could not find of anything more creative for having it done within 1 single query since the LIMIT values have to be known before executing the query.

In cases when we are not talking about huge results sets then it might be more efficient to simply fetch all results and the comments order and then use array_slice for displaying only the relevant page comments.

```
/* get the comment order */
SET @commentOrder = 0;
SELECT commentOrder INTO @relevantCommentOrder FROM (
        SELECT commentID, @commentOrder := @commentOrder+ 1 as commentOrder
        FROM COMMENTS
        ORDER BY creationDate) commentsOrder
    WHERE commentID= 45;
/* get the value we want to use in the LIMIT clause */
SET @startFrom = CONVERT(ROUND(ROUND(@relevantCommentOrder/10)*10) ,UNSIGNED);
/* fetch relevant results */
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM COMMENTS LIMIT ?,10';
EXECUTE STMT USING @startFrom;
```

The next one is 1 query that would get you the whole results set and put the comment's order in **all rows** so you could then just check the first row's relevantCommentOrder field inside PHP and then slice the array so it'd display only relevant comments, this one is only efficient if the whole results set is not too big.

```
SET @commentOrder = 0;
SELECT *, @relevantCommentOrder;
    FROM (
   SELECT commentID, @commentOrder := @commentOrder+ 1 as commentOrder, 
           @relevantCommentOrder := case when commentID = 45 
                                        then @commentOrder 
                                        else @relevantCommentOrder end 
      FROM COMMENTS
      ORDER BY creationDate ) subQuery;
```